# Visual Studio 2017 solution hangs on startup the first time

Tags: visual-studio-2017

At my company we have a Visual Studio 2017 solution that has 8 projects; 6 of them are ASP Web Forms projects, 1 class library and 1 test project for the class library. If you pull the solution from SVN and open it for the first time Visual Studio takes from 15-30 minutes to load (depending on your machine specs). Its easy to reproduce, it happens on each dev workstation. After loading the first time you can close/re-open the solution pretty fast.

If you pull down another branch from SVN (same repo) and open the solution in the new branch for the first time it hangs again. After loading the new branch .sln for the first time it opens fast. However, after you load the second branch .sln if you try opening the .sln from the first branch it hangs again. So every time you go from one branch to the next you have to wait for the .sln to load the first time (very odd I know). Its reproducible and happens every time. But again, after you get past the hanging solution and you get it loaded you can close/re-open that branch's solution very fast.

When VS hangs in the status bar it will say 'Loading project file xxx' and it will hang on 3 or 4 different projects, each for like 3 to 5 minutes before loading the next project. We've noticed if you click the X in the upper-right corner of the window to close VS you get a windows message about the app not responding. If you choose 'Close the Program' then open the solution file again it will quickly load the project that was hanging then progress to the next. Something about forcing a close causes the hanging project to load fast the next time you open that solution.

So our work-around to this issue is if you need to open a .sln for the first time, or if you opened the .sln from another branch and need to re-open a different branch, you should open the solution force a close and repeat 3 or 4 times until the solution loads. This is tedious but takes less than a minute vs waiting the 15+ minutes for VS to open the solution.

All devs on our team experience this same behavior on their respective workstation. We've even had consultants help us with various projects who experience the same behavior. It happened with VS 2015 as well.

Has anyone else experienced this and have suggestions on fixing it? I'm not even sure how best to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Move Over to Git.. it is much faster , the problem is not with Visual Studio but with SVN...

Comment: SVN isn't integrated with VS so I'm not sure why you would say its the problem. Regardless, I moved the solution/projects into a different folder that isn't using VCS but am still experiencing the same behavior. I don't think this issue has anything to do with SVN.